# How do I set HTTP response headers from python Binaris functions?

Tags: python, binaris

I'm getting started with Binaris functions implemented in Python and I want to return HTML from one of them.

[The doc on Node.js](https://dev.binaris.com/tutorials/nodejs/working-with-http/#create-the-http-response) gives an example of creating a custom response object and sets `Content-Type` header to `text/html`.

Does Binaris allow to do the same in Python?